# Location from WiFi Data

Tags: python, location, wifi, wireless, svm

We are trying to determine which room a person is in based on WiFi data. Here's a sample of our data:

1.SSID: wireless, BSSID: 00:24:6c:61:da:81, capabilities: [ESS], level: -54, frequency: 2437

2.SSID: wireless, BSSID: 00:24:6c:61:da:c1, capabilities: [ESS], level: -57, frequency: 2462

3.SSID: visitor, BSSID: 00:24:6c:61:da:c0, capabilities: [ESS], level: -58, frequency: 2462

4.SSID: visitor, BSSID: 00:24:6c:61:cb:40, capabilities: [ESS], level: -59, frequency: 2437

5.SSID: wireless, BSSID: 00:24:6c:61:cb:41, capabilities: [ESS], level: -59, frequency: 2437

This is taken from a single scan at one time-point (and I am only showing 5, but there are 60 access points close enough that come up on a single scan). Here is our problem:

There are 3 rooms, Room A, Room B, and Room C, they are all next to each other except Room B is in between Room A and Room C. There are a couple APs that are unique between Room A and Room C, but there are no unique APs in Room B.

We tried to use a multi-class SVM, with the classes being Room A, Room B and Room C, and the data points being (for example) 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 above (so in the above data there are 5 data points and every data point has the label Room A). We trained the model with around 100 scans in each room (each scan consisting of about ~50 data points). This yielded extremely low accuracy on new test data.

Is there anyone else that has done this successfully or has any recommendations? This is what we used to implement our SVM:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand how you are trying to do it... all I can think of is using the ping to each of the routers and try to play with some trigonometry in order to figure out the position, is that how you are doing it?

Comment: How do you avoid totally oversaturating the WiFi spectrum space with _sixty_ access points in range?  Don't they all interfere with each other and cause drastically reduced throughput?

Answer (score 4):

This is a clever idea, but I think you may come into some difficulty when going for precision and accuracy here, since it is NOT ONLY DISTANCE from an access point but actually A MULTITUDE of factors which determines signal strength. For instance, the location in the room as compared with a large bookshelf, or a television, might influence one of the signals more strongly than the others. Even the position of your body with respect to the device might disrupt the signal.

I suggest trying some [feature selection techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) and/or some other learning algorithms which can hone in better on which dimensions in your data are giving you the most consistent information. For example, simple statistical analysis can tell you the mean and standard deviation of signal strength of each signal from within a given "location". Then you can compare locations' statistics, and see if you have **statistically significant** differences in any of these signals across locations. You may want to consider the following tests:

- [ANOVA (ANalysis Of VAriance)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANOVA) could compare means across many locations
- [T-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-test) is like ANOVA but just for comparing pairs of locations

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is a lot of details to get right in the feature extraction and the hyper-parameter tuning (using grid-search). Please edit your question to include the script to make it possible to help you get those details right.